# How to prevent wordpress from wrapping my javascript in <p> tags

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress 3.8.1 site. I want to embed this javascript in a script tag in a page.

```
var EASTBANKRATE, POLICEANDFIRERATE, WESTBANKRATE, calculateTax, calculateTax_Homestead, calculateTax_NoHomestead;

EASTBANKRATE = 148.77;

WESTBANKRATE = 149.66;
```

I do so like this:

[image]

But when I click preview changes (or update-->preview changes) wordpress renders this markup:

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">
var EASTBANKRATE, POLICEANDFIRERATE, WESTBANKRATE, calculateTax, calculateTax_Homestead, calculateTax_NoHomestead;</p>
<p>EASTBANKRATE = 148.77;</p>
<p>WESTBANKRATE = 149.66;</p>
```

which of course returns an error:

[image]

Is there a way to queue wordpress not to interpret this javascript as markup? If not, is there any way to add this JS to the page without digging into the wordpress back end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable the `wpautop` filter to avoid converting newlines to `<p>` tags.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

[Instructions on disabling `wpautop` here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter)

Another option is to not include any double line breaks in your javascript, though this can be tricky to manage. Officially WordPress recommends referencing an external file if you have to include javascript into the post contents: [Using JavaScript in Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript#JavaScript_in_Posts).

Comment: I'm having this problem with Revolution Slider, a plugin. You can't seriously expect users to edit out the white space in plugin code? If I make a page with no content other than a single shortcode, WP puts the p tags in the output generated by the class.php file.

Comment: @TARKUS this applies to javascript in the post content, not within a plugin.

Comment: Downvoted because this solution doesn't work for javascript in post content. The linked instructions for disabling wpautop don't do anything. Also you're not supposed to link to instructions, you're supposed to give instructions. Linked pages move.